# Capybara Poltergeist/PhantomJS testing - disable javascript on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, poltergeist

On of my projects is fairly javascript intensive, so I have a `<noscript>` alert for users that might come in with Javascript disable on their browsers.

I'm trying to write a test for my test suite that just validates this behavior, but I can't figure out how to tell Capybara/Poltergeist (which I use for my feature tests) to disable javascript before making requests.  I can't find anything clear in the documentation.  Has anyone else run into something like this?

Comment: are you sure that this is a good idea? you could just use a different driver for that test, that is not js enabled like rack-test and assert on this basis. it's also faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I still have no idea how to do this in Poltergeist, but I figured out how to get it set up in Selenium:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox_nojs do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile["javascript.enabled"] = false
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```

Comment: Using this custom driver breaks Capybara. It seems Capybara requires JS to interact with the page during tests. How did you fix this?

Comment: At least on the version of Capybara that I use, JS is not required.  Can you point me to where you're seeing that Capybara requires javascript?

Comment: You can see what I've got here:https://gist.github.com/DivineDominion/ae672f24be394bac4fae

Comment: Have you tried changing 'feature 'Contact form POST without Ajax', :js => false do' to 'feature 'Contact form POST without Ajax' do'?